# Are there any custom open-source applications that use openssh?

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, ssh, openssh

So I have some specific environment (like linux os based phone) so I have no such thing like terminal. All I can do is create my own UI's using C++ and some SDK I am provided with.

I want to create an ssh client application for my device. Its not a work, nor a homework - just for fun that means I have lots of time for solving conflicts that may appear.

My main problem is I have never worked with [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) as a lib... and when I look on it it seems some large mountain to me.

So I ask for your help - have you seen any open-source ssh clients that use SSH methods with their own UI's based on OpenSSH or, better [Portable OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/portable.html)?

Comment: Maybe you want something like [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/)?

Comment: What is "costum"? Did you mean "custom" or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) for example.

Comment: does not putty use standard windows std::cout for output?

Comment: i haven't managed it's source but as i can see it creates it's own console window, not system console window.